# Printing Submit button for each row

Tags: php, sql-server, button, input, submit

I have problem with my buttons. I will try to explain.
1)I have users db from postgresql and new db in ms sql.
2)Created site with 2 columns in table ("SELECT * from users"-postgresql ): They are id/user
3)Then added new column "Operator" which contain submit buttons and functionality of submit buttons is updating "access" column from ms sql db.

PROBLEM:
It prints all buttons for all data that I have in ms sql(I have 7 rows data in ms sql, it prints 7 buttons for each row), I need to "echo" 1 button for each row which will be changable. If access==1 it should be named Active , else it should be named Diactive.

Here is my code and picture of what I got:

```html
<?php
<table class="table table-condensed">
   <thead>
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>User</th>
  <th>Operator</th>
  <th>View</th>
</tr>  
<?php
 while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
  ?>
<tr>
 <td>
  <?php
  $id = $row["id"];
  echo $id;
  ?>
 </td>
 <td>
  <?php
  $username = $row["username"];
  echo $username;
  ?>
 </td>
 <td>
  <form method="POST" action="oper.php">
<?php
include ("db.php");
 
$result2 = pg_query($db_connection, "SELECT * from users ORDER by id asc");
while ($row1 = pg_fetch_array($result2)) 
{
 $iddrain= $row1['id'];
 //echo $iddrain;
   
  
 //echo $iddrain;
 $q7= "Select access from nezeret where id_m=$iddrain";
 
 //var_dump($q7);
 $resultid= sqlsrv_query($link, $q7, $params, $options); 
 while($row7= sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultid))
 {
  //$rs7=$row7['ID_M'];
  $rs8=$row7['access'];
  //echo $rs8;
  //break;
 
 if($rs8==1)
  {
   echo "<p><input type=\"submit\" name=\"uid\" value=Operator-ON onchange=\"this.form.submit()\"></p>
    <p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"uid\" value=$id onchange=\"this.form.submit()\"></p>"; 
  }
 
  else
  {
   echo "<p><input type=\"submit\" name=\"uid\" value=DIavtive onchange=\"this.form.submit()\"></p>
    <p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"uid\" value=$id onchange=\"this.form.submit()\"></p>"; 
  }
 }
}
?>     
        </form>
 </td>
<?php
 }
?>



</tr>
</table>
?>
```

[image]

Comment: put <form> </form> inside the loop in if else condition 

make `value="Deavtive" `

 value="Active"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve changed code and now it is working, problem was additional useless fetch. Here is the code:

```html
<table class="table table-condensed">
   <thead>
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>User</th>
  <th>Operator</th>
  
</tr>  
<?php
 while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
  ?>
<tr>
 <td>
  <?php
  $id = $row["id"];
  echo $id;
  ?>
 </td>
 <td>
  <?php
  $username = $row["username"];
  echo $username;
  ?>
 </td>
 <td>
  <form method="POST" action="oper.php">
<?php
include ("db.php");
 
 $iddrain= $row['id'];

 $q7= "Select * from nezeret where id_m=$iddrain"; 
 //var_dump($q7);
 $resultid= sqlsrv_query($link, $q7, $params, $options); 
 while($row7= sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultid))
 {
  $rs8=$row7['access'];
  //echo $rs8;

 
  if($rs8==1)
  {
   echo "<p><input type=\"submit\" name=\"uid\" value=Operator onchange=\"this.form.submit()\"></p>
    <p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"uid\" value=$id onchange=\"this.form.submit()\"></p>"; 
  }
 
  else
  {
   echo "<p><input type=\"submit\" name=\"uid\" value=Nazeret onchange=\"this.form.submit()\"></p>
    <p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"uid\" value=$id onchange=\"this.form.submit()\"></p>"; 
  }
 }

?>     
        </form>
 </td>


</tr>
<?php
 }
?>

</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing typo mistake na dnot giving quote for value attributes near :

try like this :

```
 if($rs8==1)
    {
        echo '<p><input type="submit" name="uid" value="Operator-ON"  onchange="this.form.submit()"></p>
        <p><input type="hidden" name="uid" value="'.$id.'"  onchange=
    "this.form.submit()"></p>'; 
    }

   else
   {
        echo '<p><input type="submit" name="uid" value="DIavtive"  onchange="this.form.submit()"></p>
                 <p><input type="hidden" name="uid" value="'.$id.'  onchange="this.form.submit()"></p>'; 
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reditted your code to remove some errors that were making it fail to work;

```
<?php include ("db.php"); ?>    
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Operator</th>
                    <th>View</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>        
    <?php
 //while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {

      <?php foreach( pg_fetch_array($result) as $row ) { ?>
     ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td<?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <form method="POST" action="oper.php">
    <?php 
        $result2 = pg_query($db_connection, 'SELECT * from users ORDER by id asc');
     while ($row1 = pg_fetch_array($result2)) {
         $iddrain = $row1['id'];
         $q7 = "Select access from nezeret where id_m=$iddrain";

        //var_dump($q7);
        $resultid = sqlsrv_query($link, $q7, $params, $options);
         while ($row7 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultid)) {
             //$rs7=$row7['ID_M'];
            $rs8 = $row7['access'];

            if ($rs8 == 1) {
                echo '<p><input type="submit" name="uid" value=Operator-ON onchange="this.form.submit()"></p>
                        <p><input type="hidden" name="uid" value=$id onchange="this.form.submit()"></p>';
            } else {
                echo '<p><input type="submit" name="uid" value=DIavtive onchange="this.form.submit()"></p>
                        <p><input type="hidden" name="uid" value=$id onchange="this.form.submit()"></p>';
            }
         }
     }  
     ?>     
                </form>
            </td>


        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```